# What is the term shortlink structure?

Tags: terms, shortlink

I know I can access to posts with this url structure : `mysite.com/?p=X` where X is the post ID. It's convenient because it will work even if the permalink for this post is modified.

But you you now if there is a similar structure for terms (categories, tags...) ?

I tried

```
?t=term_id
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked [into the following documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Category_base_and_Tag_base) to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are referring to what are the query string keys are, it will depend on the taxonomy you are working with, for

- **categories**: you are looking for `?cat=cat_id`
- **tags**: you are looking for `?tag=tag_slug`
- **custom taxonomy**: it depends on the slug of the tax but it will look like `?taxonomy_slug=item_slug`

Check the definition of the [default WP query vars keys](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1403) for more info

**EDIT**

As per you comment, I thought I would share this too. If you need/want to search by `term_id` (regardless of custom tax or not) you would need to add a custom query string (query vars) and modify the main query to do so.

Here's how you could do this

```
// Add your custom query var so WP can listen for that query string too
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_add_custom_query_vars' );
function my_add_custom_query_vars( $vars ){
  $vars[] = 'my_var';
  return $vars;
}


// Then modify the query to include all taxonomies, searching by tax ID
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );
function my_custom_query( $query ){
  $my_id = absint( get_query_var( 'my_var' ) ); // retrieve the var defined above

  $tax_query_args = array(
    array(
      'field'         => 'term_taxonomy_id',
      'terms'         => $my_id,
    ),
  );

  $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
  $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query_args );

}
```

My example could be expanded to listen for multiple `term_id` so you could use a query string like `?my_var=1,2,3` to return any posts within `term_id` `1 OR 2 OR 3` or `?my_var=1+2+3` to return any posts within `term_id` `1 AND 2 AND 3`. But as a general basic concept, this is how you would do it.

Comment: So for custom taxonomy, you can't use the term id ?

Comment: it doesn't look that way,  if you look further down at [line 1897](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1897) into query.php, you'll see that for custom taxonomy, the slug is used, as opposed to categories ([line 1956](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1956)) the `term_id` is used instead. If you really need/want to look for content by `term_id` you' d have to make your custom query arg and modify the main `$wp_query` accordingly

Comment: @Matthieu updated my answer to show how to use a custom query to get custom taxonomies by `term_id`